# Why does Visual Studio disconnect a TCP Socket gracefully, when i press "Stop Debugging"?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sockets, tcp

I'm using Visual Studio 2022. I have a client and a server console application (code below).

- **Server**: waits for a connection, then waits until a line is typed (something followed by ENTER), and then sends the int `3`
- **Client**: connects, and waits to receive an int

**Scenario**

- I start the server **with debugging**
- I start the client **without debugging**, and let it connected so that it waits to receive an int.
- Then i stop the server process, without typing a line, in one of the following ways:

  - If i stop the server by closing it's console window or kill it with Process Explorer, then the client
    has a `SocketException` (ErrorCode 10054) as expected
  - If i stop the server by pressing the "Stop Debugging" button in Visual Studio or kill it with Process Explorer, then the client receives 0 bytes (a graceful disconnect). But i expect the same `SocketException`

**Question**

Why does Visual Studio disconnect the Socket gracefully?

**Server code**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Server
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("server");

            var local = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 12345);
            
            var listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            listener.Bind(local);
            listener.Listen(int.MaxValue);

            Console.WriteLine("accept...");
            Socket sock = listener.Accept();
            Console.WriteLine("read line...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("send...");
            int n = sock.Send(BitConverter.GetBytes(3));
            Console.WriteLine($"done. sent {n} bytes");
        }
    }
}
```

**Client code**

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Client
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("client");

            var sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            Console.WriteLine("connect...");
            sock.Connect("127.0.0.1", 12345);

            var buffer = new byte[sizeof(int)];
            Console.WriteLine("receive...");
            int n = sock.Receive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            Console.WriteLine($"done. received {n} bytes");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By default, when a console window is closed, active processes in it will terminate themselves immediately via `ExitProcess()`. Tools like Task Manager, Process Explorer, etc are a little nicer about how they exit an external process, they will try to exit the process gracefully before brute-forcing it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau if i start the server with debugging and kill it with Process Explorer, then it disconnect gracefully, if i start the server without debugging and kill it with Process Explorer, then the client throws a `SocketException`. so i think something else is going on. i've now edited my question to state this

Answer (score 1):

On my side, the behavior is different, same code and same operations(start server with debug and start client without debug, input nothing and then stop debug of server) still cause SocketException(You expected) on my side. So I think the situation you encountered should not be the default behavior.

My steps:

[image]

I think the issue should comes from some settings of your VS2022, or the version of your VS tool.

Please try to reset the [environment settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2022#reset-all-settings):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Since the server and client should belong to devenv.exe, you can also try to reset the settings via the command of devenv:

[/ResetSettings (devenv.exe)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/resetsettings-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022)

By the way, the version of the VS2022 on my side is 'community 17.4.4':

[image]

Comment: i tried it on a different system and it behaves properly there, so it looks like it something specific to the first system. both systems have VS2022 Community 17.3.5. resetting to all the collections you showed didn't solve it. `devenv.exe /ResetSettings General` also didn't solve it. i'm going to try an update. what did you use to make that nice video? thanks for the effort

Comment: updating to Community 17.4.4 didn't solve it unfortunately. maybe i need to reinstall Visual Studio or Windows 10

Comment: you need to reset to default "The World" nuget package